# Api call to an EC2 instance in VPC from lambda function getting times out(At times other times it works fine) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, node-request

We have server running on EC2 which is under VPC. we consume its API from a Lambda Function which has all the access to VPC.

As our lambda functions is getting called from API gateway(with VPC link) we only have a window of 29 sec.
At times lambda executes successfully other times it gives time out(request does not even reached to ec2 server).

We are not doing any heavy processing in in our EC2 server. technically server running on EC2 should gives response in 2 sec. we tried running it with rest client(postman) it always responds in 2 sec.

we are not sure why it gets failed at time from Lambda function.

We are using "request" module of nodeJS to make the API call from Lambda.

We are also observing the same behavior on calling different lambda function through API gateway.

This Issue is very confusing as at times it executes successfully other time it breaks.

We are not sure if its Network issue or we have something wrong in our code.

here is how we are hitting API

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request.get({url:url}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
if (err) {
   console.error('failed:'+err);
   reject(err);
}
console.log('successful!  Server responded with:',body);
resolve(body);
```

}); });

P.S. we dont have any SSL configure in EC2
 Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you make sure every subnet you assign to your Lambda function has routes to the EC2-Instance (i.e. the local route hasn't been messed with)? Does your EC2 instance allow connections from Lambda based on IP-Whitelisting or a security group? (If it's the former, make sure all relevant IPs are whitelisted and think about switching over to the latter)

Comment: we have created multiple subnet and security groups also added all the subent and security groups to lambda.
does adding unnecessary subnet or security group makes lambda slow to connect to end server ?